# Byte order of file content

Tags: c, endianness

I wrote single cyrillic character `А` into file. It's hex representation in UTF-8 encoding is `0xD090`. Then I read file's content, but for some reason result was different.

Here's function I'm using to print binary representation of number:

```
char* bstr32(int val) {
    char* res = calloc(33, 1);

    for (int a = 31; a >= 0; a--) {
        res[a] = val & 1 ? '1' : '0';
        val >>= 1;
    }

    return res;
}
```

That's how I read data from file (size of file is hardcoded and error checks are omitted):

```
int main() {
    unsigned char buff[2];

    read(open("data", O_RDONLY), buff, 2);

    puts(bstr32(*((unsigned short*) buff)))
}
```

Output: `00000000000000001001000011010000`

Same value but defined in code:

```
int main() {
    puts(bstr32(0xD090))
}
```

Output: `00000000000000001101000010010000`

I figured out that data read from file is in little endian format, using `htonl` will produce correct result. I wonder why does result is different despite bitwise operators are endian independent?

Comment: UTF-8 is a series of bytes, with each byte of an encoded codepoint interpreted in turn. You're reading a 16 bit value instead, where endianness comes into play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `puts(bstr32(*((unsigned short*) buff)))`, you take two bytes in memory and load them as a `short`, which, in your C implementation, puts the low-addressed byte in the high bits of the `short`, and then that `short` is displayed with its high bits first.

So the bytes are in the file the same way they were originally in memory, but your attempt to display them using a `short` presented them in reverse order.